# GL_FRONT_AND_BACK in glCullFace()

Tags: opengl

As per documentation OpenGL allows using `glCullFace()` with `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK`, but I struggle to come up with any examples of where this would be useful. Do you know about any real-world use cases for `glCullFace(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK)`?

Answer (score 2):

A possible use would be to turn off rasterization and just execute the vertex level shaders without needing to set up transform feedback.

But I think the real reason is that it is easier to implement and think about. You have two control bits in the render pipeline, one to cull front facing, one to cull back facing. Four combinations, 00, 01, 10, 11. Why make one of them a special case? If someone wants to cull both front and back, just let them do so rather than adding yet another error code.